How to save a pdf loaded dynamically to local file using Microsoft WebView2?
I want to download a pdf from the page displayed in WebView2 control to local file.
The page looks like:
<html><head></head><body style="height: 100%; width: 100%; overflow: hidden; margin:0px; background-color: rgb(51, 51, 51);"><embed name="6DAB3236688D0EC02F1865BE24F467BD" style="position:absolute; left: 0; top: 0;" width="100%" height="100%" src="about:blank" type="application/pdf" internalid="6DAB3236688D0EC02F1865BE24F467BD"></body></html>

Can't use WebClient due to restrictions.WebResourceResponseReceived does not contain the pdf. Should I use execScriptAsnyc to run script to get the pdf?
Hopefully there will be an answer from SO visitors. Thank you.

I found a workaround, maybe someone will have something more elegant then this:
private void webView21_CoreWebView2InitializationCompleted(object sender, Microsoft.Web.WebView2.Core.CoreWebView2InitializationCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    webView21.CoreWebView2.SaveAsUIShowing += CoreWebView2_SaveAsUIShowing;
}

private void webView21_NavigationCompleted(object sender, Microsoft.Web.WebView2.Core.CoreWebView2NavigationCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    webView21.CoreWebView2.ShowSaveAsUIAsync();
}
private void CoreWebView2_SaveAsUIShowing(object sender, CoreWebView2SaveAsUIShowingEventArgs e)
{ 
    e.AllowReplace = true;
    e.SuppressDefaultDialog = true;
}

